Docker Desktop File browser will only open some folders on initial launch of container
This is a problem with Docker Desktop for Windows, running Ubuntu containers. I wanted to socialize this to see if others are experiencing this same problem (and maybe hit on a cause/solution).
Launching a new container and going to Files will allow all folders to be opened/edited/saved to outer O/S (Windows). However, if you navigate away you will no longer be able to open all folders. Folders will sometimes appear open for a quick instance but if you "close" the folder no amount of restarts will let you open the folder.
The folders where this happens do not appear to be protected (permissions are fine when accessing via command line docker -exec with bash).  I was working around this by copying the files (via bash) to a new folder, however recently accessing that new folder has also stopped working.
When I restart the container it sometimes does allow access - for <5 minutes, then it starts disallowing access again.
Reproduce:
Start a container (something like ngnix or tomcat)
Go to files and try to open /usr
back out to container page (the page that lists all running containers)
Go back into files for container and "close" /usr
try opening /usr again
Fails: the folder expands for only 0.1 second before collapsing quickly.
Expected behavior
Should open the folder to view files
Reported by 2-3 people on Docker Desktop github https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13984
I tried restarting the container, then restarting Docker Desktop, then updating Docker desktop, shutting down Docker and WSL and restarting everything, etc. all to no avail.
